# MVC 5 Model Binding

Tags: session, asp.net-mvc-5, model-binding

I use MVC5 and ASP.NET. I want to use model binding. How can i get session object in model binding.

```
   public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {

       //I need session here

    }
```

Comment: Are you creating a custom `ModelBinder`? To do what (I cant see a reason why you would need an object from session in this context)?

Comment: `HttpContext.Current.Session`?

Comment: I've found my fault. I was implement it from wrong model binder. I've implement it from System.Web.Mvc.IModelBinder and ControllerContext parameters has came.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SessionPictureModelBinder:System.Web.Mvc.IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var obj = controllerContext.HttpContext.Session["MyKey"];
        return obj;
    }
}
```